# Python tasks and DAGs with different conda environments

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, airflow

Say that most of my DAGs and tasks in AirFlow are supposed to run **Python** code on the **same machine** as the AirFlow server.

Can I have **different DAGs** use **different conda environments**? If so, how should I do it? For example, can I use the **Python Operator** for that? Or would that restrict me to using the **same** conda environment that I used to **install** AirFlow.

More generally, where/how should I ideally activate the desired **conda environment** for each DAG or task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python that is running the Airflow Worker code, is the one whose environment will be used to execute the code.

What you can do is have separate **named queues** for separate **execution environments** for **different workers**, so that only a specific machine or group of machines will execute a certain DAG.

Comment: Do you have links to docs on the bolded terms above? It would be helpful to be able to read up more.